Missing libtiff.5.dylib for running an executable-Unix-file on macOS 14.5 (Apple Silicon)
When trying to run this application by opening the FaceLandmarkVid executable-Unix-file from the downloaded ZIP, my Apple Silicon macOS terminal says the following:
dyld[5840]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libtiff/lib/libtiff.5.dylib   

Referenced from: <CD88BE10-D723-3786-BFB4-65023B8912DB> /Users/myName/Nextcloud/Applications/OpenFaceBinOSX/libopencv_imgcodecs.3.3.dylib   

Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/libtiff/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/opt/libtiff/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/opt/libtiff/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/usr/local/Cellar/libtiff/4.6.0/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/Cellar/libtiff/4.6.0/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/Cellar/libtiff/4.6.0/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache) 

zsh: abort      /Users/myName/Nextcloud/Applications/OpenFaceBinOSX/FaceLandmarkVid  
Saving session... ...copying shared history... ...saving history...truncating history files... ...completed. Deleting expired sessions...none found.  [Prozess beendet]

So it seems that libtiff.5.dylib is missing.
Since OpenFace is required for this OSC Client, I successfully built the original OpenFace repository on my M2 Mac running with Sonoma 14.5 (after some struggles).
I then verified my libtiff installation via ls /usr/local/opt/libtiff/lib/ where I got
libtiff.6.dylib     libtiffxx.6.dylib   pkgconfig
libtiff.a       libtiffxx.a
libtiff.dylib       libtiffxx.dylib

Following that: Do I simply need to install libtiff.5.dylib on my system, or do I maybe need to tell the Unix file to choose another version of this library?
I couldn't figure out how to install libtiff.5.dylib for my system since when doing brew install libtiff I got
Warning: libtiff 4.6.0 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 4.6.0, run:
  brew reinstall libtiff

Can somebody give me a hint on how to proceed from here? Many thanks!
